# PyQt5 Error displaying html: js: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcore, qtwebengine

I have a html file which I want to display in a PyQt5 window. I've created a MWE below. When I try to run the code I get the error "js: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined". I assume this is a javascript error(?) but I'm not familiar with javascript and could well be wrong.

I've narrowed the error down to the line "view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(map_path))".

How can I fix this error? Or is there another way to display the html file? Thanks.

```
import os
import folium

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets, QtCore

current_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]

My_map = folium.Map(location = [50.819767,-1.087977], zoom_start=4)
My_map.save('map.html')
map_path = os.path.join(current_dir,'map.html')

app = QApplication([])

view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(map_path))
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you use any proxy? Or verify that your firewall is preventing js from downloading.

Comment: @eyllanesc You're correct, the firewall was preventing js from downloading. I tried the code on a different computer without a firewall and it worked fine. Thanks.